# window.location.href behavior explanation needed

Tags: javascript

I've noticed that when you don't bind window.location.href to some event browser doesn't let me go back in page. Please explain why is it this way

```
   let link = document.getElementById('link');

   link.addEventListener('click',function(){
    window.location.href = "v.html"
   })

// the code above works just fine and i can go back in history afterwards
// I can't do the same with the code below

   if(1){
      window.location.href = "v.html"
   }
```

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't let me go back", exactly? What behaviour are you experiencing? And on which browser(s)? It's always helpful to know what _is_ happening instead of what _isn't_ happening.

Comment: How are these two snippents of code being run? In a script tag on load?

Comment: That isn't true. open your console and type `window.location.href = "https://google.com"` - your browser will honor that request. Then, still in the console type `window.history.back()`. You will return to the previous page.

Comment: browser is google chrome, 
go back in history - means i click the "back arrow" of browser, 
the code is run in a script tag without any onload event in the <body>

Comment: Is that an example? Or exactly what you are doing? If your url contains fragments (`v.html#whatever`) then yes, history won't work as expected.

Comment: I'm in "a.html" file. The file got html skeleton and inside the body tag script tags are opened where i write only one of those 2 codes from my example. One works as I expect it to work, the other one doesn't

Comment: But what does it do instead? You still didn't explain. Instead of letting you go back, what happens instead? Nothing? An error? Something else?

Comment: Are you sure it's not going back? Sounds like it's going back, then your code is running again and it's immediately changing the href URL again. If you're changing the URL to `v.html` as soon as the page loads, whenever you go back it'll just return you to `v.html` right away.

Comment: it doesn't go back cause back button is inactive. My question is why is that button inactive

Comment: @Adyson in first case it goes to v.html and then I can go back to a.html via clicking the "back arrow". In second case it also goes to v.html, but the "back arrow" is inactive.Thats the difference